# Different table layout with correct numbering

Tags: tables, numbering

Is there a way to make some of my tables look like this:

[image: Example of table]

In particular, I cannot get the table numbering to work automatically. It is now manually set, but I would like this to be numbered according to the table counter, and to be able to label it and refer to it. The code of the image is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.95\linewidth]
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{Table 10.2: Some axioms}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $\top \leq a \to a$
      \item $\top \to \bot \leq \bot$
    \end{itemize}
  \end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I see, your equations are automatically numbered by use of `enumerate`. What you mean with " I would like this to be numbered according to the table counter". So far your table number is manually set. Please, clarify this and also extend your code sniped to complete small document, which produce showed image.

Comment: Oops I meant the table number. I changed the question so that there is no enumerate in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in your preamble:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable}{ m }
  {
   \begin{tcolorbox}[width=.95\linewidth]
     \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{table} % ❶
     \textbf{Table \thetable: #1}% ❷
     \par
  }
  {
     \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  }
```

and then in your document:

```
\begin{mytable}{Some axioms}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $\top \leq a \to a$
    \item $\top \to \bot \leq \bot$
  \end{itemize}
\end{mytable}
```

Of course `tcolorbox` includes the `\newtcolorbox` command which can integrate all of this for you so you don't need to declare the environment. See `texdoc tcolorbox` for the hair details. I'm not sure that, for this case, it makes things easier, but if you wanted to, say, offset the title in some way, it can make your life a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Another posibility: by use of `\captionof` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Axioms}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.95\linewidth]
\captionsetup{font=bf}
  \begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Some axioms}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $\top \leq a \to a$
      \item $\top \to \bot \leq \bot$
    \end{itemize}
  \end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]